# Отображение в консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вообщем строка в консоли должна изменяться в 0.5 сек: C этого символа '/' через 0.5 сек на этоn '-' потом
через опять 05 сек на этот '' в цикле до 50 раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

разбиваем задачу на этапы:

1. цикл до 50 раз
2. отрисовка соответствующего символа
3. ожидание 0.5 сек

цикл можно задать через команду `range`

```
for cycle in range(50):
```

отрисовывать символы можно через команду `print`, но так, чтобы не было перехода на новую строку, а был бы "возврат каретки"

```
print(letter, end="\r")
```

понятное дело, что `letter` у нас будет попеременно то `/`, то `-`
это удобно сделать через массив и привязать к циклу, например так:

```
letters = ["-", "/"]
letter = letters[cycle % 2]
```

ну а ожидание можно сделать через команду `time.sleep()`

```
time.sleep(0.5);
```

правда понадобится библиотека `time`, которую можно включить через команду `import`

осталось все это соединить вместе :)

Comment: Оно то так но вот ошибка     
letter = letter[cycle % 2]
NameError: name 'letter' is not defined

Comment: Ище я бы хотел спросить: как мне поставить знак "\" потому что он используеться как зарезервированный в пайтон.

Comment: @NNEETT34, опечатался - `letter = letters[]` - к массиву же обращаемся

Comment: @NNEETT34, используйте "\\" - почитайте про эскейп-последовательности

Comment: У меня будет подледный вопрос: Как после этого цикла очистить эту строку и вывести надпись?

Comment: @NNEETT34, поскольку постоянно при выводе строки она заканчивалась возвратом каретки, т.е. не было перехода на новую строку, то обычный `print("какая-то надпись")` перетрет все